# ORA-12154: Nagios checks

Tags: oracle, nagios, ora-12154

I have got Oracle DB's version 18 and version 19 and they all work fine but the Nagios monitoring checks for v19 all give me:
`CRITICAL - ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.` I even have got on one server both versions but monitoring checks for v19 not working. They are all set the same way (tnsnames.ora, and .cfg in monitoring serv.) but I still missing something for v19 only.

Tried to find the same issue on the internet but I didn't. Also checked the connection and is DB work and is OK. Compared to the conf. files from v18 and v19 looks OK.

Comment: (I find SO/SE to work best with explicit questions.)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you use correct credentials when it comes to user and password in -l and -a
I also experienced this kind of errors in past, during creation of checks but proper USER solve it.